# Feedback notice should say "downvotes" rather than "votes"

Tags: bug, reputation, voting, down-votes, privileges

Voting up needs 15 reputation, voting down needs 125 reputation.

If a user with enough reputation to upvote but not to downvote attempts to downvote, they are presented with the message:

[image: downvote notice box]

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

This sentence is not strictly correct.  Upvotes *do* change the publicly displayed post score.  The sentence should be rephrased to correctly state that it is only referring to downvotes.

Comment: I guess they chose an easy way by using string pattern "*Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than [rep_needed_to_vote] reputation ...*" and apply it *both* for <125 rep when downvoting *and* <15 rep when upvoting...

Answer (score 2):

While I agree that technically it should say "downvotes", the user knows what button they just clicked so the context of the message should be clear.

As Somewhat says in [their comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315054/feedback-notice-should-say-downvotes-rather-than-votes#comment1032740_315054) the message is probably a standard one with the reputation value picked from the database because as well as differing for up- and down- votes it varies depending on whether the site is in private beta or not. While this shouldn't be used an excuse for not fixing the bug, it explains why the problem is happening and also indicates that any fix will probably cost more in development and testing time than any benefit it might bring to the site.